# Standard Properties and Methods on HTML elements does not work with FullCalendar 'element'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I'm working with `JQuery FullCalendar` and I just tried to use a call back function `eventRender` and call the `element.getAttribute()` as in the code sample.

but it says `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getAttribute'`

Why is this happening ? 
[this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) Standard Properties and Methods on HTML elements does not work with the `element` object. As it [the FullCalendar documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) says `element is a newly created jQuery <div> that will be used for rendering. It has already been populated with the correct time/title.` But I can't call that methods and properties on that `element`

Code :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        editable: true,
        events: [
            {
            title: 'First',
            start: new Date(2014, 1, 24, 8),
            end: new Date(2014, 2, 3, 8)
            },
            {
                title: 'Second',
                start: new Date(2014, 2, 3, 8),
                end: new Date(2014, 2, 10, 8)
            }
        ],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {              
                alert(element.getAttribute("id"));               
        },
        eventAfterRender : function(event, element) {
                alert(element.getAttribute("id"));                       
        },
        eventAfterAllRender: function(event, element) {
                alert(element.getAttribute("id"));                       
        }

    });

});
```

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `element` is not a dom element reference, it is a jQuery object so you need to use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
element.attr('id')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4wYkT/)

---

Or you can access the actual dom element using `element[0]` or `element.get(0)`

Comment: great. Thanks. BTW is there any documentation which clearly state Standard Properties and Methods we can use for a `jQuery object` ?